# Spring Boot 1.3.7 Cross Origin Configuration Not Working

Tags: spring-boot, jhipster

I have my Spring Boot (1.3.7) application configured to enable CORS support.  I've setup the cors filter in WebConfigurer and verified the code is getting executed that creates the CorsFilter.  However, I am not seeing the access-control-allow-origin attribute in my response header and not sure why. Is there some other configuration in Spring Boot that I'm missing to get CORS working?

My application.yml contains the cors configuration as follows in the jhipster: section

```
cors: #By default CORS are not enabled. Uncomment to enable.
        allowed-origins: "*"
        allowed-methods: GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS
        allowed-headers: "*"
        exposed-headers:
        allow-credentials: true
        max-age: 1800
```

My Application code (minus some unimportant details)

```
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {
        MetricFilterAutoConfiguration.class,
        MetricRepositoryAutoConfiguration.class,
        MongoAutoConfiguration.class,
        MongoRepositoriesAutoConfiguration.class,
        EmbeddedMongoAutoConfiguration.class,
        EmbeddedMongoProperties.class})
@EnableConfigurationProperties({JHipsterProperties.class})
@EnableEurekaClient
public class App {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(App.class);

    @Inject
    private Environment env;

    @PostConstruct
    public void initApplication() {
        if (env.getActiveProfiles().length == 0) {
            log.warn("No Spring profile configured, running with default configuration");
        } else {
            log.info("Running with Spring profile(s) : {}", Arrays.toString(env.getActiveProfiles()));
            Collection<String> activeProfiles = Arrays.asList(env.getActiveProfiles());
            if (activeProfiles.contains(Constants.SPRING_PROFILE_DEVELOPMENT) && activeProfiles.contains(Constants.SPRING_PROFILE_PRODUCTION)) {
                log.error(
                        "You have misconfigured your application! " + "It should not run with both the 'dev' and 'prod' profiles at the same time.");
            }
            if (activeProfiles.contains(Constants.SPRING_PROFILE_DEVELOPMENT) && activeProfiles.contains(Constants.SPRING_PROFILE_CLOUD)) {
                log.error(
                        "You have misconfigured your application! " + "It should not run with both the 'dev' and 'cloud' profiles at the same time.");
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException {
        SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(App.class);
        SimpleCommandLinePropertySource source = new SimpleCommandLinePropertySource(args);
        Environment env = app.run(args).getEnvironment();
        log.info("\n----------------------------------------------------------\n\t" + "Application '{}' is running! Access URLs:\n\t"
                + "Local: \t\thttp://127.0.0.1:{}\n\t" + "External: \thttp://{}:{}\n----------------------------------------------------------",
                env.getProperty("spring.application.name"), env.getProperty("server.port"), InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress(),
                env.getProperty("server.port"));

        String configServerStatus = env.getProperty("configserver.status");
        log.info(
                "\n----------------------------------------------------------\n\t"
                        + "Config Server: \t{}\n----------------------------------------------------------",
                configServerStatus == null ? "Not found or not setup for this application" : configServerStatus);
        addDefaultProfile(app, source);
    }

    private static void addDefaultProfile(SpringApplication app, SimpleCommandLinePropertySource source) {
        if (!source.containsProperty("spring.profiles.active") && !System.getenv().containsKey("SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE")) {

            app.setAdditionalProfiles(Constants.SPRING_PROFILE_DEVELOPMENT);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: One thing to add and not sure its relevant, I am returning ResponseEntity<?> types on my restful services.  I know I can manually add header information to that response type but I figured the auto CORS configuration would add that and it doesn't seem to be doing it.

Comment: Will you post your configuration file and your main application file?

Comment: I updated my original question to specify the configuration in my application.yml for the cors configuration.  I also added the application class minus package specification, imports and comments.

Comment: It is probably something with the JHipster properties being loaded after Spring doe the CORS initialization. You could add a separate `@Configuration` class for the CORS configuration.